# Unmapping keys for a specific buffer(quickfix) only?

Tags: quickfix

I usually have `j` and `k` bound to `gj` and `gk`, respectively for navigating wrapped lines. But this becomes annoying when I have to use the **quickfix window**, so I thought of using something like :

```
augroup QuickFix
     au FileType qf unmap j
     au FileType qf unmap k
augroup END
```

But this undoes the mapping for the **main buffer** as well, so I tried `unmap <buffer> j` and `unmap <buffer> k` instead but this produces an `E31: No such mapping` error and the `gk`, `gj` bindings still seem to persist.
The command that I am testing this using is `:vimgrep "TODO" %`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `unmap` I simply did a buffer-local ([`:h :map-local`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-local)) mapping back to the original values...

```
augroup QuickFix
     au FileType qf map <buffer> j j
     au FileType qf map <buffer> k k
augroup END
```

Ran `vimgrep` per your example and in the quickfix window I have `j`/`k` behavior while still maintaining `gj`/`gk` function in the main window.

**Update:** Interesting (and somewhat lengthy) side bar regarding the mapping commands used above. @LucHermite asked a valid question in the comments: "Shouldn't [the auto commands use] `noremap`?" He asked because what happens with `map` and the other *non*-noremap mapping commands is that keys on the RHS of a defined mapping retain any mappings they already have. This can actually result in a kind of "infinite loop" where a LHS key triggers a RHS key that is mapped to the LHS key which triggers the mapped keys again and repeat, ad infinitum.

It seems pretty clear then that `map j j` should result in just such an endless cycle. But it works fine. How? Well, there is a specific exception to the behavior I described which is noted in [`:h recursive_mapping`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#recursive_mapping):

> If the {rhs} starts with {lhs}, the first character is not mapped again.
> For example:
>
> :map ab abcd
>
> will execute the "a" command and insert "bcd" in the text.  The "ab" in the
> {rhs} will not be mapped again.

That being said, I'm normally a stickler for using the noremap commands. I just kind of locked in on the fact that `map` works correctly and answers OP's question but `noremap` is better because, at the very least, it's a good idea to get in the habit of using it *always unless you know explicitly that you need `map`*.

**TL;DR: Though both are valid I recommend using `noremap` instead of `map` in the auto commands above.**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `noremap`?

Comment: @LucHermitte Check out my (long) update.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: @LucHermitte Thanks for motivating me to address it. :)